# PHPMailer Gives Error Message: "PHP Parse error: parse error, unexpected '{' in mailer.php on line 23"

Tags: php, phpmailer, parse-error

I made a website for a club of my university and I used PHPMailer. When I try it in my own server, it works perfectly. However after I upload the site to the school's FTP, my PHPMailer is not working. I contacted the school IT and they said: "The version of PHP on the server is 4.3.9. Codes that you wrote must be suitable for it. In server's error logs we got the following error: PHP Parse error:  parse error, unexpected '{' in mailer.php on line 23".
I checked my codes billion times but I cannot solve the problem on that. Here is my code:

```
<?
if(!empty($_POST['sender_mail'])
    || !empty($_POST['sender_name'])
    || !empty($_POST['sender_surname'])
    || !empty($_POST['sender_major'])
    || !empty($_POST['sender_schoolyear'])
    || !empty($_POST['sender_id']))
{
  phpinfo();
    require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
    include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded
    $smail = $_POST['sender_mail'];
    $name = $_POST['sender_name'];
    $surname = $_POST['sender_surname'];
    $major = $_POST['sender_major'];
    $schoolyear = $_POST['sender_schoolyear'];
    $id = $_POST['sender_id'];

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telli ng the class to use SMTP

    try { // Here is 23th line
      $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
      $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
      $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
      $mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
      $mail->Username   = "xxxxx@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
      $mail->Password   = "xxxxxxx";            // GMAIL password
      $mail->AddAddress('xxxxx@gmail.com', 'Membership');
      $mail->SetFrom('xxxxx@gmail.com', 'GGK');
      $mail->Subject = 'New Membership';
      $mail->IsHTML(true);
      $mail->Body = '<h3>New Membership</h3><br/><i><b>Name: </i></b><i>' . $name . '</i><br/><b><i>Surname: </i></b><i>' . $surname . '</i><br/><b><i>Mail: </i></b><i>' . $smail . '</i><br/><b><i>ID: </i></b><i>' . $id .  '</i><br/><b><i>Schoolyear: </b></i><i>' . $schoolyear . '</i><br/><b><i>Major: </b></i><i>' . $major . '</i>';
      $mail->Send();
      echo "Message Sent OK</p>\n";
    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        echo -1;
      echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo -1;  
      echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
    }
}
else{
    echo -1;
}
?>
```

Note: I got all values of the form with ajax and post them to mailer.php.

Comment: My IDE says no error, are you sure that's the right code\file ?

Comment: Don't believe that `try`, `catch` or the exceptions model existed in php before version 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try/catch is only in PHP5 versions. You'll need to do other error catching (if/else) in order to do the tests.

Comment: what do you suggest for the alternative way of try/catch in PHP4?

Comment: even better upgrade the php version 4.3.9 is dangerously old (22 Sep 2004) and unsupported "Support for PHP 4 has been discontinued since 2007-12-31. Please consider upgrading to PHP 5."

Comment: I cannot upgrade the version of PHP. School's IT doesn't allow to change it.

Comment: they are fools, but you can host else where. just because its a school club does not mean it has to be hosted on the school server.

Comment: Looking at the source code for PHPMailer, you won't be able to use it at all on that version of PHP. You'll either have to find a version of PHPMailer that works on PHP 4.3.9, use php's internal mail() function, or beat your school's IT department into upgrading their extremely outdated server. Or, as Dagon said, host elsewhere.